# почему не происходит переход на сайт по ссылке?

Tags: html

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset = "UTF-8">
<html>
<head>
<title>наука.ру</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Привет мир</h1>
<p><strong>Моя первая веб-страница</strong></p>
<p><a href = "www.astronews.ru">Нажмите сюда</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Но по клику на ссылку не переходит на сайт. В чём дело?

Comment: В том виде, что написано - по ссылке происходит поиск файла по относительному пути в текущей директории, очевидно такого файла нет. Указывайте нормальный URL

Answer (score 5):

Вместо этого:

```
<p><a href = "www.astronews.ru">Нажмите сюда</a></p>
```

Вставь это:

```
<p><a href = "http://www.astronews.ru">Нажмите сюда</a></p>
```